Running mistral:instruct through ollama in colab is very slow
I want to use colab's GPU when running ollama. To be able to run it I use ngrok to set the tunnel.
All works fine and I can pull model and use it. However, even though I use mistral/instruct which should be quite small (4 gb), the scoring is very slow. Please see the code below:
!pip install openai
!pip install instructor
!pip install aiohttp pyngrok

!curl https://ollama.ai/install.sh | sh

import os
import asyncio

# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so the system NVIDIA library
os.environ.update({'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/usr/lib64-nvidia'})

import os
os.environ["OLLAMA_HOST"] = "0.0.0.0"

import threading
import time
import os
import asyncio
from pyngrok import ngrok
import threading
import queue
import time
from threading import Thread
from google.colab import userdata

# Get your ngrok token from your ngrok account:

token="YOUR_NGROK_TOKEN"
ngrok.set_auth_token(token)

# set up a stoppable thread (not mandatory, but cleaner if you want to stop this later
class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def is_stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

def start_ngrok(q, stop_event):
    try:
        # Start an HTTP tunnel on the specified port
        public_url = ngrok.connect(11434)
        # Put the public URL in the queue
        q.put(public_url)
        # Keep the thread alive until stop event is set
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            time.sleep(1)  # Adjust sleep time as needed
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in start_ngrok: {e}")

# Create a queue to share data between threads
url_queue = queue.Queue()

# Start ngrok in a separate thread
ngrok_thread = StoppableThread(target=start_ngrok, args=(url_queue, StoppableThread.is_stopped))
ngrok_thread.start()


while True:
    try:
        public_url = url_queue.get()
        if public_url:
            break
        print("Waiting for ngrok URL...")
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in retrieving ngrok URL: {e}")

print("Ngrok tunnel established at:", public_url)


import os
import asyncio

# NB: You may need to set these depending and get cuda working depending which backend you are running.
# Set environment variable for NVIDIA library
# Set environment variables for CUDA
os.environ['PATH'] += ':/usr/local/cuda/bin'
# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include both /usr/lib64-nvidia and CUDA lib directories
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/lib64-nvidia:/usr/local/cuda/lib64'

async def run_process(cmd):
    print('>>> starting', *cmd)
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *cmd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    # define an async pipe function
    async def pipe(lines):
        async for line in lines:
            print(line.decode().strip())

        await asyncio.gather(
            pipe(process.stdout),
            pipe(process.stderr),
        )

    # call it
    await asyncio.gather(pipe(process.stdout), pipe(process.stderr))

import asyncio
import threading

async def start_ollama_serve():
    await run_process(['ollama', 'serve'])

def run_async_in_thread(loop, coro):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.close()

# Create a new event loop that will run in a new thread
new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

# Start ollama serve in a separate thread so the cell won't block execution
thread = threading.Thread(target=run_async_in_thread, args=(new_loop, start_ollama_serve()))
thread.start()

So far so good. I set the connection and ollama serve is running...
!ollama pull mistral:instruct

Here how I use the llm:
from openai import OpenAI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List

import instructor

class ReferenceDetails(BaseModel):
  title: str
  doi: str

client = instructor.from_openai(
    OpenAI(
        base_url="http://localhost:11434/v1",
        api_key="ollama",  # required, but unused
    ),
    mode=instructor.Mode.JSON,
)

def ExtractTitleDoi(dfInput):

    dfRes = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for index, row in dfInput.iterrows():
        
        try:
            text = row['JOINED_LINE']
    
            resp = client.chat.completions.create(
              model="mistral:instruct",
              messages=[
                  {
                      "role": "user",
                      "content": "Extract the title and doi info from the text: " + text + "if doi is not in the text return empty string",
                  }
              ],
              response_model=ReferenceDetails,)
    
            ti = resp.title
            doi = resp.doi
    
            dfRes = pd.concat([dfRes, pd.DataFrame([row['REF_PK'], text, ti, doi]).T], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    
     
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    return dfRes

%%time
extractTiDOI = ExtractTitleDoi(df.head(5))

I always need a json output due to which I employ instructor.
Is it because colab or am I doing something wrong? Any other suggestion getting results way faster would be highly appreciated.
EDIT: Just noticed that when installing ollama with
!curl https://ollama.ai/install.sh | sh

the following warning pops up:
WARNING: Unable to detect NVIDIA/AMD GPU. Install lspci or lshw to automatically detect and install GPU dependencies.
But when run the code in kaggle notebook it is automatically installed. However, it is still very slow.
